# Mixed object responses when multiple calls are sent at the same time to API endpoint

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, angular8, api-design

In my API, I have a use case that handles file uploads to Google Cloud Storage. When a request object is received, the information is first logged to my database and then uploaded to GCloud. However, when multiple individual uploads are sent together [POST] (ex. 5 files), the uploaded files are correctly logged into the database and uploaded to the cloud storage but the responses to the caller are mixed up. For example, if I send 3 individual request for 3 files within a few ms interval, the responses will sometimes be mixed (ex. the same file is returned twice to the caller and one is missing). However, when I refresh the page, everything is fine since the data is properly stored.

Here is my use case code :

```
        public async Task<bool> Handle(FileUploadRequest message, Interfaces.IOutputPort<FileUploadResponse> outputPort)
        {
            string uploadedFileName, signedUrl;

            try
            {
                uploadedFileName = UploadFile(message);
                signedUrl = SignUrl(uploadedFileName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.Error(e, "Error uploading to GCLOUD.");
                outputPort.Handle(new FileUploadResponse(new Error("Action Failed", "Failed to upload file to the Google Cloud service.")));
                return true;
            }

            var response = await _fileRepository.
                Create(new Domain.Entities.File(
                    message.UserId,
                    message.DocTypeId,
                    message.File.FileName,
                    uploadedFileName,
                    DateTime.Now,
                    message.Visible
                    ));

            if (response.File != null)
                response.File.Url = signedUrl;

            outputPort.Handle(response.Success ? new FileUploadResponse(response.File, true) : new FileUploadResponse(new Error("Action Failed", "Error attempting to upload file.")));

            // logging
            if (!response.Success)
                logger.Error(response.Errors.First()?.Description);

            return response.Success;
        }
```

Now for the front-end side of things, this is how the requests are sent :

```
    this.attachedFiles.forEach((file) => {
        if (file.uploadStatus === this.fileUploadStatuses.Uploading) {
            this.http.post<FileResponse>(`${this.baseUrl}/File/upload`, file)
                .toPromise()
                .then(uploadRes => {
                    if (uploadRes) {
                        this.uploadSuccess.emit(uploadRes);
                        this.uploading -= 1;
                        file.uploadStatus = this.fileUploadStatuses.Uploaded;
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    this.uploading -= 1;
                    file.uploadStatus = this.fileUploadStatuses.Failed;
                });
        }
    });
```

At this point, I don't know wether the issue is from the API or from how the requests are sent. Any help is appreciated.